# Modal backdrop in css doesn't make color transparent

Tags: angular

I need to make color of modal dialog backdrop transparent, from some reason I can't do it,
my css and html are in next lines
CSS

```
.modal-backdrop {
    background-color: transparent;
  }
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="notificationModal" >
<div class="modal-dialog notification modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: #009ee2;">
            <span class="modal-title col-md-3" style="color: white; font-size: 25px; padding-bottom: 0.5rem;">
                Notifications</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body" style="color: black; padding-top: 0px;">
      
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <div style="height: 0.25rem;"></div>
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Zatvori</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm opening modal on next way

```
<li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="navbar-nav-link" data-toggle="modal" 
                    data-target="#notificationModal">
                    <i class="icon-bell2"></i>
                    <span class="d-md-none ml-2"></span>
                    <span class="badge border-white ml-auto ml-md-0" style="color: white;">10</span>
                </a>
            </li>
```

Comment: None of your HTML elements actually have the class `modal-backdrop` on them.

Comment: where is the right place?

Comment: https://tutorialdeep.com/live-editor/disallow-bootstrap-modal-open-on-click-outside-using-html/
just add .modal-backdrop {
    background-color: transparent;
  } in style

Answer (score 0):

In the example link you posted in the comments, that's a Bootstrap 3 modal so just change `data-backdrop="static"` to `data-backdrop="false"`. Here is the documentation that explains how to do this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-options

Edit:

If you want a non-static (i.e. clickable) but transparent background, add the following

```
.modal-backdrop.in {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: If I change from static to false, I can't get closing on outside click

Comment: The example you posted was using static which already means you can't close it on outside click...

Comment: @eRes See my edit for how to do with non-static backdrops.

Comment: I added that lines in css, but it doesn't work...

Comment: Here is a working example https://jsfiddle.net/d519foqk/. I'd recommend learning how to debug css through the browser dev tools.

Comment: Is possible I have older version of bootstrap?, because whatever I try it doesn't work...

Comment: when I open modal dialog I see I got one class on bottom of html but It doesn't allow me to affect on value, do you know any way if user click outside of modal dialog to dialog dissapear

Comment: Post a full working version of your code.

Comment: bootstrap": "^5.0.15"

Comment: The tutorial you posted is using Bootstrap 3.